# react-native-admob compatibility with wix react-native-navigation

Tags: ios, react-native, admob, react-native-navigation

I'm using [wix/react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) router ([tab based app](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/top-level-api?id=starttabbasedappparams)) and [react-native-adbmob](https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob) package for [AdMob Rewarded Video Ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video).

On Android, it works well, but on the iOS, when I try to show a Reward ad in `react-native-navigation` Modal window (`this.props.navigator.showModal(config)`), it is not visible although the `adOpened` event is fired.

Has anybody faced the same or similar issue with other packages?